# The problem creates a thumbnail after insertion

Tags: java, image, alfresco, document, cmis

I use alfresco 7.1.0 with embedded ImageMagick 7.0.10. In global.properties I have system.thumbnail.generate=true. In Tomcat I have file thumbnail-service-context.xml and I use CMIS connector.
Alfresco does not automatically create a thumbnail. If I open a folder in Alfresco UI, then I will wait a few seconds to create a preview only, then do I have a preview in CMIS.
Can you please advise me what is wrong, if the thumbnail does not create itself after insertion?

Thanks,
Robo

Comment: I seem to remember that CMIS uploads don't trigger the thumbnail generation by default - maybe try the approach from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10487135/generating-thumbnails-in-alfresco-4-0-d ?

Comment: Thanks for the help. Do you know how to set the context (properties) in CMIS, pls?

Answer (score 0):

We dont have any direct way available from CMIS Client. could you try

```
cmis.create.doc.request.renditions.set=doclib,pdf
```